# Vagrant how to set network type so that its attached to bridge adapter on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am using Vagrant to created Virtual Box images.  Can anyone tell me the configuration I can set that the Virtual Box VM Network that attaches the VM to a **Bridged Adapter** before starting up.

I can set the following configuration in my `Vagrantfile`, but it sets the Network adapter to NAT not bridged adapter that I need.

```
config.vm.network :public_network
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that all network interfaces are either NAT or not set? Because the first interface will always be a NAT and the second should become the bridge in your scenario.

Answer (score 6):

I am installing vagrant on ubuntu 10.04 with Virtualbox VirtualBox 4.1.24 from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads and then downloaded recent version of vagrant.

```
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant version 1.2.2

$ dpkg -l virtualbox*
ii  virtualbox-4.1 4.1.26-84997~U Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

In order to use bridge network and specifically wifi i just added the line below inside **Vagrantfile**

```
 config.vm.network :public_network, :public_network => "wlan0"
```

When you will do

```
 $ vagrant up
```

You will see option asking for device for bridge interface you can use 1 for wlan0. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did something different like this one:

    `config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.11.3.251", :public_network => "eth0"`

this allows me to set a static IP for my VM as I needed one for tracking purposes

Answer (score 5):

Vagrant will setup a default NAT network, you can add a bridge network by uncommenting the following line in Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

However, if you have multiple network devices in your host, You can specify which one to use by the `bridge` parameter:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: 'en4: AX88179 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet'
```

Comment: the `en4` is on host machine running virtualbox or is it on the vm running virtual box ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today, 
what I have really done using Vagrant 2.2.0, use this directive inside my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "wlp3s0: Wi-Fi (Hackathon)"
```

it is also possible to use:

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

and Vagrant will ask whether you use WLAN or nic!IF THE