# vm instance not setting up default to Bridged mode when using vagrant on Windows

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, virtualbox

I have tried to follow this thread: [Vagrant how to set network type so that its attached to bridge adapter on Virtual Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816444/vagrant-how-to-set-network-type-so-that-its-attached-to-bridge-adapter-on-virtua) with similar problem but no success.

Also tried this: [How to automatically select bridged network interfaces in Vagrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250304/how-to-automatically-select-bridged-network-interfaces-in-vagrant)

and Vagrant docs https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/virtualbox/configuration are Linux specific.

This is my vagrant file.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "xoan/proxmox-ve_6.4"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8006, host: 8006

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  config.vm.network "public_network", auto_config: false, Bridged: 'Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #5',  ip: "192.168.56.2",
    nic_type: "virtio"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    vb.gui = true
  
    # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
    vb.memory = 2048
    vb.cpus = "2"
    vb.name = "proxmox1"
  end
end
```

I am specifying the NAT to bridged mode and giving it the Ethernet card name as VirtualBox sees it. (specifying the name since I have multiple nic interfaces)

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'xoan/proxmox-ve_6.4'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'xoan/proxmox-ve_6.4' version '1.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: proxmox1
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8006 (guest) => 8006 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
```

but everytime I run vagrant up I keep getting NAT 1 as default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarded to 127.0.0.1 are to the correct NAT, you should try to ping the ip `192.168.56.2` from your host machine. You you should be able to ssh this ip using the pivate key i.e.

```
ssh -i private_key 192.168.56.2
```

Comment: yes I was able to ping and ssh, strangely it does not shows the ip being assigned printed in terminal. 
I was able to ssh using the private key